# Python - Print substrings until matches for all matches

Tags: python, findall

I am looking to find all matches in a `string` and print all substrings until I match these `strings` to a new line.

e.g.

```
"123ABC97edfABCaaabbdd1234ABC0009ui50ABC_1234"
```

should `print`:

```
ABC97edf
ABCaaabbdd1234
ABC0009ui50
ABC_1234
```

where `"ABC"` is the `pattern` match which is recurring.

Is there an efficient way I can do so using findall?

- New to Python here, using python version 2.4.3

Edit just an F.Y.I:
What I am trying to do is basically I have a 250+Gb file which has control characters showing start and end of line but these Ctrl Characters (because of issues.. mostly network) are embedded within these lines i.e. in between the start/end indicating control characters.

With that, there is no specific distinction between the start/end control chars and the ones that come in between these messages.

So I am basically removing these control chars, and have I wish to have a complete message per line pertaining to some specific regex.

The regex here is not necessarily ABC or in order for all of these messages. 
I have tried using findall and am able to find all the matches, just I did not know how to get the strings following these until i find the next match. (the regex here can be either -ABC=35nga|DEF=64325:dfaf:1234| or **ABC=35632|DEF=61 and many different forms.

And I have to break for each line and for the ones which have multiple lines embededed within a line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also what are the substrings? Please take a look at [mcve].

Comment: If possible use a newer Python version.

Comment: Version 2.4 has been outdated for more than 11 years.

Comment: @Bahrom: Substrings vary and have no particular order, I have a few tokens that repeat

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Unfortunately, not for this specific task

Comment: @NicholasFlees: I agree, hands tied here though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using `re.findall`:

**See the `regex` in action on [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/YeqjEy/1).**

```
s = "123ABC97edfABCaaabbdd1234ABC0009ui50ABC_1234"
re.findall("ABC.*?(?=ABC|$)",s)
```

which gives a `list`:

```
['ABC97edf', 'ABCaaabbdd1234', 'ABC0009ui50', 'ABC_1234']
```

---

And if you wanted to `print` the `elements` in this `list`, you could simply do:

```
for sub in re.findall("ABC.*?(?=ABC|$)",s):
    print(sub)
```

which would `output`:

```
ABC97edf
ABCaaabbdd1234
ABC0009ui50
ABC_1234
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! Turns out I was on the right track and I needed to build the regex properly. ++1 for the regex101 link ^_^
I got it to work.. Upvoted as you pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: Please `accept` instead of `up-voting`, as you do not have sufficient reputation for `up-voting` to do anything! Glad I could help you out **:)**